# Retrieve header(location) value of response using javascript

Tags: javascript, business-process-management

I am trying to retrieve the value of "Location" from the response I get from an API call. The response does not have any body, but it contains a value(URL) in the Location section of the header. 
Any way I can get the value of header using javascript. The response variable that i am using is of type XML. This is being implemented in IBM BPM 7.5

Comment: Is the service returning a `302` or other `3xx` status code, or is this a `200` with a `Location` header?

Comment: Hi Jacob, this is a 200 with location header. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, the `Location` header of a response comes in conjunction with a `3xx` status code.  Unfortunately, with AJAX, redirects are followed, so you cannot inspect the header of a redirect response.

However, if your response is not a redirect, you can use the `getAllResponseHeaders()` function to inspect your headers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer jacob. How can I find if the response is a redirect or not? Just new to all this stuff!!

Comment: I don't think there's a way to detect redirects in JavaScript, but you could use something like Firebug to see your traffic.